Boundedness of the sequence $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}\right\}$.
I want to study the boundedness of the sequence $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}\right\}$. In one of my old post $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$, we got that: the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$$
doesn't exist. Specifically, the sequence $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}\right\}$ is unbounded or $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}\right\}$ doesn't admit a finite limit. Actually, in that post, we proved that(due to Conrad's nice answer):
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n+1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}\right)\neq0.$$
Further more, it is not clear whether the sequence $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}\right\}$ is bounded or not. If it is unbounded, can it be
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}=\infty?$$
I don't have enough tools to deal the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k}$,
any help and hints will welcome! Thanks for your attention.

Will it be helpful to consider $\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{sin(\frac{n}{k})}{k}$? I tried to make use of $1<\frac{2n}{k}<2, n+1<k<2n$, but I'm not sure whether this will work.

@aawangas Possibly, but it's then hard to say if the lower half won't cancel out or overwhelm any trend in the upper half.

@User123732 So the Dirichlet test fails and we can't conclude anything. Actually, we already know the sequence doesn't converge.

@
User 123732
What's the meaning of $\sin(n/k)=\omicron_{k\to\infty}(\sin(nk))$? Could you say more?

WolframAlpha Result

This function appears to be increasingly well approximated by the power series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\zeta\left(2k+2\right)}{\left(2k+1\right)!}x^{\left(2k+1\right)}-C
$$
as $x$ increases, where
$$
C = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!\left(2k+1\right)}.
$$
This might be a good direction to explore in. I don't think what I have is a true proof, but you can see my derivation in this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kf7o0ufvfh

@Polygon
Thanks for your valuable comment!

Another way of looking at the problem: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k \sin\left(\frac nk\right)$ is an evenly-spaced Riemann sum of $\frac1x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$ over $(0, 1]$. For what it's worth, the indefinite integral of this function from $0$ to $1$ is a finite number. But that still doesn't imply that these sums are bounded, as far as I can tell.

Update: the power series that I found earlier equals the infinite sum of the same expression:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k \sin\left(\frac xk\right).
$$
It follows that the the constant $C$ is the same sum from $x+1$ to $\infty$, which is equal to $\text{Si}(1)$. I am not sure if this is actually helpful, but hopefully it is worth something.

It is bounded.
By Abel's summation formula, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\sin\frac{n}{k} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sin \frac{n}{k}}{n}+\int_1^n \frac{\sum_{k \le t} \sin\frac{n}{k}}{t^2}dt,$$ so it suffices to have $$\Bigl| \sum_{k \le t} \sin \frac{n}{k}\Bigr| \le \frac{t}{\log^2 t}$$ for $t \in [\sqrt{n},n]$ (say). But, we know this is true (by a lot). See e.g. here.
